# Sending emails using loopback email connector

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I am trying to use `loopback-email-connector` to send emails. I want to setup 2 email accounts. I am doing the following in `datasources.json`.

```
"emails": {
        "name": "emails",
        "connector": "mail",
        "transports": [
            {
                "type": "smtp",
                "host": "smtp.yandex.com",
                "secure": true,
                "port": 465,
                "tls": {
                    "rejectUnauthorized": false
                },
                "auth": {
                    "user": "a1@abc.com",
                    "pass": "password"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "smtp",
                "host": "smtp.yandex.com",
                "secure": true,
                "port": 465,
                "tls": {
                    "rejectUnauthorized": false
                },
                "auth": {
                    "user": "a2@abc.com",
                    "pass": "password"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

In above case I have added 2 email accounts - `a1@abc.com` and `a2@abc.com`.
To send email, I am doing the following:

```
app.models.Email.send({
      to: 'foo@bar.com',
      from: 'a1@abc.com',
      subject: 'my subject',
      text: 'my text',
      html: 'my <em>html</em>'
    }, function(err, mail) {
      console.log('email sent!');
      cb(err);
    });
```

This is successfully  sending the email. But if I use from email as `a2@abc.com`, it doesn't work.  I get the following error:

```
Error: Mail command failed: 553 5.7.1 Sender address rejected: not owned by auth user.
```

But if I move, `a2@abc.com` as the first email in datasources.json, it works.
In fact, which ever email comes first in the `datasources.json` only that works, the second one is not working. How can i setup multiple email ids in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure out a way which does not involve creating multiple datasources for each email.

Setting `alias` for each transport assigns an alias which can be used while sending emails. In respect to the above question, we can do something like below:

```
"emails": {
        "name": "emails",
        "connector": "mail",
        "transports": [
            {
                "type": "smtp",
                "host": "smtp.yandex.com",
                "secure": true,
                "port": 465,
                "alias": "a1",
                "tls": {
                    "rejectUnauthorized": false
                },
                "auth": {
                    "user": "a1@abc.com",
                    "pass": "password"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "smtp",
                "host": "smtp.yandex.com",
                "secure": true,
                "port": 465,
                "alias": "a2",
                "tls": {
                    "rejectUnauthorized": false
                },
                "auth": {
                    "user": "a2@abc.com",
                    "pass": "password"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

After setting the `alias` as above, to send email, we can use the `alias` as transport.

```
app.models.Email.send({
      to: 'foo@bar.com',
      from: 'a1@abc.com',
      subject: 'my subject',
      text: 'my text',
      html: 'my <em>html</em>',
      transport: "a1"
    }, function(err, mail) {
      console.log('email sent!');
      cb(err);
    });
```

In the above example, I have set `a1` alias and am sending email by setting transport as `a1`. This works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The mail server is rejecting your email because you're trying to send  a mail which is not same with your email option.

Just try to update `a1@abc.com` with your mail `a2@abc.com` like following:-

```
app.models.Email.send({
  to: 'foo@bar.com',
  from: 'a2@abc.com',
  subject: 'my subject',
  text: 'my text',
  html: 'my <em>html</em>'
}, function(err, mail) {
  console.log('email sent!');
  cb(err);
});
```

You have to keep same email ids in your transports config and "from-to" email.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response but if you read my question, that is what I am asking. I am adding 2 emails, both a1 and a2 in the datasources.json, whichever comes first in the list is able to send mail. I want both of them to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through following steps:

1)Create 2 different datasource, with a different name and add single emailId to each. One datasource you have already made, from that just remove one emailId and attach to another one.

2)Create a new model(Ex. TestMail) by command `lb model`, set one datasource you want to attach with for sending mail.

3)Now you have two models, one `Email` and other `TestMail`, now just use `send()` with your required mail model.

This worked for me!

Comment: Thanks Shubham, but I figured out a better solution by setting `alias` in each transport object. For eg: `alias: "a1"` To send email, I just have to send a transport key with `alias` name. This way, I do not need to create other datasources.

Comment: This solution sounds good, is it possible to have a demo. I just want to go through the best optimum solution.

Comment: I have added an answer with complete code above. Please have a look at that. Thanks